# Android image won't scale to menu icon

Tags: android

I have the following navigation view:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>
```

Which uses the following item:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile_icon"
    android:title=""/>
```

In my MainActivity, i load a profile fragment. When the profile image of the user is retrieved by an API, i assign the profile image to the menu profile icon like this:

```
BottomNavigationView navigationView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
MenuItem profileMenuItem = navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.navigation_profile);
int desiredWidth = profileMenuItem.getIcon().getIntrinsicWidth();
int desiredHeight = profileMenuItem.getIcon().getIntrinsicHeight();
//SelectedImageBimap contains the profile image retrieved from the API
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedImageBitmap, desiredWidth, desiredHeight, false);
Drawable profileImageDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), scaledBitmap);
profileMenuItem.setIcon(profileImageDrawable);
```

The profile image is the following (only the part in the circle):

[image]

But it does not scale to my menu and it loads like this (white part):

[image]

What should i do for the image to scale correctly?